# Change the selectedIndex in a combo box according to data loaded from a database (PHP)

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

I have a database of Employees and a dropdown list which I generated with PHP, then with javascript I tried to put the right type of blood of each employee in the database.

I have a database of Employees and a dropdown list which I generated with PHP, then with javascript I try to put the right type of blood for each employee in the database.

First I retrieved the data:

```
$rsEmployee = employee::getEmployees();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsEmployee))
        {
    echo "
    <select id='slcBloodType' name='slcBloodType' onload='chooseItem(this, '$row['slcBloodType']')'>
    <option value='A+'> A+ </option>
    <option value='A-'> A- </option>
    <option value='B+'> B+ </option>
    <option value='B-'> B- </option>
    <option value='AB+'> AB+ </option>
    <option value='AB-'> AB- </option>
    <option value='O+'> O+ </option>
    <option value='O-'> O- </option>
    </select>";
}
```

The javascript function:

```
function elegirOption(list, value){
                array = ["A+", "A-", "B+", "B-", "AB+", "AB-", "O+", "O-"];

                index = -1;
                for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                    if(value == array[i]){
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(index != -1){
                               this.selectedIndex = index;
                            }
            }
```

But is not working, it seems that I can't pass a php variable as a parameter to a javascript function...

There are others dropdown list with which I want to do that.

Comment: You are correct, you can't _directly_ access PHP variables in JavaScript. PHP is server side and JavaScript is client side.

Comment: add some alerts in your code. Anyway you should really clear this: `'chooseItem(this, '$row['slcBloodType']')'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it like this:

```
$blood_types = array("A+", "A-", ...);
echo '<select>';

while(....) {

  foreach($blood_types as $blood_type) {
    echo '<option';
    if($blood_type == $row['slcBloodType'])
       echo 'selected="selected"';
    echo '>'.$blood_type.'</option>';
  }
}
```

You don't have to specify the value attribute since it's the same as the text.

Answer (score 1):

First you have several issues with your code such as duplicated IDs which is bad. Gere is how i'd do it, this is a massive cleanup of your code but should make it very close to what you had:

**At the beginning of your page**

It's always better to load your data in memory and then reuse it later below in your output. And no, unless you have 1 million lines, memory shouldn't be an issue...

```
<?php
//Read my data i need to work with
$rsEmployee = employee::getEmployee();
$employees = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsEmployee)){
    $employees[] = $row;
}
```

**Further down in your page header**

Now at this point we'll create the initialization code... You need JQUERY to make this work. It's a very good browser agnostic way to work and saves you HEAPS of trouble.

```
?><script>
    $(function(){ <?php
        foreach($employees as $employee){ ?>
        $('#slcBloodType<?php echo $employee['id']; ?>').val('<?php echo $employee['slcBloodType']; ?>');
        <?php } ?>
    });
</script><?php
```

**Further down in the HTML portion of your page**

Allright, at this point, now you output the HTML and make sure your id's are unique:

```
<?php foreach($employees as $employee){ ?>
<select id="slcBloodType<?php echo $employee['id']; ?>" name="slcBloodType[<?php echo $employee['id']; ?>]">
    <option value='A+'> A+ </option>
    <option value='A-'> A- </option>
    <option value='B+'> B+ </option>
    <option value='B-'> B- </option>
    <option value='AB+'> AB+ </option>
    <option value='AB-'> AB- </option>
    <option value='O+'> O+ </option>
    <option value='O-'> O- </option>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

Good luck applying this better coding technique, it'll save you HEAPS of trouble later if you start coding like this right now!

Answer (score 0):

> But is not working, it seems that I can't pass a php variable as a parameter to a javascript function...

This is because you **cannot directly** pass a PHP variable to javascript.

Your options are:

1. Setting cookies in PHP which javascript can later read
2. Have PHP echo the javascript code and inbetween have PHP variables printed out. For example:

   < script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

   var levels ="< ?php echo $levels ? >" ;

   < /script >